# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main SOAP UI

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to work with a web service through SOAP UI and I am getting this error:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am running the webservices on a local tomcat. Tomcat 7 running Java 1.6. The services were compiled in Java 1.6. The web services seem to be online, I am able to hit a url that lists the services available. However when I run my soap request I get the error above. The request is valid. Anyone have an idea what is going on here?

Comment: Your server is missing the class `com.sun.tools.javac.Main`.

Comment: I added the tools.jar to the tomcat lib and it worked. You can make an answer and I'll accept, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the error: Your server is missing the class `com.sun.tools.javac.Main`.